# add new row to JTable from a Different class

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, defaulttablemodel

I want to add data to a JTable which is situated on a JTabbedpane. Data which I want to insert in JTable is a user input data(TextField) from a different class named (addcontact). cntctus is the tab in which Jtable is situated. it contains a method to insert a new row to JTable.

when I am giving values to **tname** textfield(user Input) a **nullpointerexception** occurs on the line :- 
 //**contctus.addData(new Object[]{,,,}**

my problem is similar to this, Applied all the solutions mentioned. but still getting **nullpointerexception**
[Data from JTextField to JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875517/data-from-jtextfield-to-jtable)
but in my case, the class for input data is different. 
I am providing image for contctus tab. ![.][1]
this is the cntctus class:-

```
public class cntctus extends JPanel{

JPanel p,tablepanel;
JLabel labelpic;
static JTable table; 
int j,i,k=0;
String column[];
Object [][]row;
 private static DefaultTableModel model;
public cntctus() 
{

    String column[]= { "Name","Position","Phone"};
    Object [][]row = {{"Prof. g", "Director", "+123456"},
            {"Mr. Suir singh", "Assistant Professor", "+9123568989"},
            {"Ms. sa", "BI teacher","9468645"},
            {"bhbnjk ","nj","k780"},
            {"nb","hbj","9798679"}
    };
    model=new DefaultTableModel(row,column);
    labelpic =new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:\\Workspace\\nikhil\\bin\\Resources\\cont.png"));
    table = new JTable(row,column);
    TableColumn colum = null;
    table.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",15,13));
    TableModel tm = table.getModel();
.
.
.
}
```

//and here is the method for adding new row

```
 public static void addData(Object[] data) {
  //String nextrow=Integer.toString(model.getRowCount());
  model.addRow(data);
}
```

I am invoking this method from addcontact class. JTable contains three columns. 
 now dynamically i want to add more contacts in my JTable with the help of addcontact class. 
when i'll be clicking on submit button i wish to put all the three details in Jtable.
a part  of Code for addcontact class is :-

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aes) {
    Object src=aes.getSource();
    if(src==submit){
    if(tname.getText().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill contact name!!");

    }
    else
    {


        cntctus.addData( new Object[]{tname.getText(), tpos.getText(), tnum.getText()});

        //validate();

    }
    if(tpos.getText().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill contact details!!");
    }
    if(tnum.getText().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill contact number!!");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger and tell us what is null.

Comment: there is a problem in AWTEvent-0 ( nullpointerexception). when i am clicking on a button which is responsible for inserting data in JTable.

Comment: It's impossible to guess with the current state of your question. You need to provide more code. What is `cntctus`? Where is it initialized. What two classes are you referring to? How are you currently trying to access fields from one class to the other. YOur code doesn't show _any_ of that, and those are all critical points we need to see.

Comment: need more reputes to provide image. tell me if you want me to elaborate it more.